# sign in via facebook account (in codeigniter)

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have a simple website that calculates grades of college students. There are different subjects for each department. Each department has almost 42 subjects. I am thinking of providing a username/password authentication to users so that they don't have to input grades for each subject every time. But I do not want users to register on my site by filling a sign up form. I want them to log in via their face book account. I am thinking about it but I can't figure out how i can do this. I have developed my site in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked for the same solution, here is my blog post about it:

http://blog.biernacki.ca/2010/11/a3m-a-codeigniter-account-authentication-authorization-module-installation/

a3m for CodeIgniter is pretty good at doing what you want, plus it offers all the other openid providers (other than facebook)

Comment: +1 for A3M. An absolutely essential library if you're wanting OpenID integration in your Codeigniter applications. Elliot Haughin's library is still good as well if you just want Facebook integration.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "Facebook Connect CodeIgniter" should find you all sorts of resources. For example: http://www.haughin.com/code/facebook/

Answer (score 0):

you could implement openid, there are loads of tutorials on that. then you can port facebook to openid using the methods provided here: [Best way to implement Single-Sign-On with all major providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061537/best-way-to-implement-single-sign-on-with-all-major-providers)
so you have a single sign on functionality with all major providers (google,yahoo, aol, facebook, ...)