# Customized button for facebook connect

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I want to show my own custom image for facebook connect. How can I do it?

Comment: Which button? Login button, logout button, like button, what button? Also, are you using FBML?

Comment: Login button. No I am not using FBML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Oauth2.0 protocol to do the user authentication.

The javascript libraries by facebook are just a service you can but don't have to use.

It is described in detail here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/desktop

You basically just have to direct the user to a link, and analyze the link (serverside) when the user gets redirected back.

What button/link/image you use in your frontend is then all up to you.

There is also a nice port of facebook to openid available here, that you may be interested in: [Best way to implement Single-Sign-On with all major providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061537/best-way-to-implement-single-sign-on-with-all-major-providers/4127343#4127343)